# how Speed up compilation CGAL library

Tags: c++, performance, compilation, cgal

Hi stackOverflow comunity.

I been studying and making a programm in c++ using the CGAL library ( and others ) but my problem is that it takes a huge compilation time. I'm not extacly an expert with C++ ( i start programming for make physics simulations and i still have a lot to learn ) so i dont know how i can make this process much faster. 
At the moment i have a .cpp with a lot of "#includes" to the CGAL library and the rest of the code( classes and etc) , i think all this includes are the botleneck in the compilation... i been reading about precompiled headers but i dont find a way to use it in mi cmake script... even try a utility called cotire, but i dont see a positive effect...

Thanks for your reading and answers :) 
the compilation is made by a cmake script included with the CGAL.

Comment: http://www.cgal.org/FAQ.html#compilation_speed

Comment: Hi! about the use of precompiled headers... how i can use those files in mi cmake script?, CGAL generates an cmake for compilation.thanks

Answer (score 0):

Three possibilities:

1. try to split your cpp file in several files; in order to decrease the number of #include in each cpp file;
2. use make -j XX (for example make -j 8) if you have a multi core processor;
3. use ccache, a compiler cache.

Comment: mmm is funny, in the CGAL FAQ says that is better to agroup all the headers in a single header file. will try somethings thank for your answer